# CSS iframe won't move

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty new to HTML and CSS, and I've looked for an answer to this for awhile but I can't seem to find anything. I have an iframe element that I'm trying to position , but whenever I change the left or right properties it doesn't actually move.

```css
.things1 {
  position: relative;
}

.afx-vid {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="things1">
  <iframe class="afx-vid" width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rndV_5q8Tkc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

I know this probably seems like a dumb question but some help would be appreciated :)

Comment: works perfectly fine for me. However I find it questionable why you do something like this with an absolute and relative positiong if youc ould do the same with margins.

Comment: ok turns out i was just being stupid. it wouldn't show up when i reloaded the page over and over, but it showed up once i searched the website into the search bar again

Comment: always clear the cache or press the reload button - as the issue is not reproduciable please remove the question voluntarily.

Answer (score 0):

You code will actually move the `iframe`, but this is not a good way to do that. I recommend you use `flex` property to move your elements on your website.

`flex` is super easy and it will make your learning so much easier.

There are tons of youtube videos and websites that explain how `flex` works, so please watch them, it will help you. :)

Here is your fixed solution. Just replace your current `css` with this one :

```
.things1 {

  width : 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}

.afx-vid  {

  margin : 0px auto;

}
```

You always assign `display : flex;` to the parent of the element(s) that you want to move (in this case, you want to move .afx-vid, and his parent is .things1, so we give .things1 display : flex;).

`justify-content : center;` is one of the properties you can use when you declare `display : flex;`. What it basically does is align items on x-axis (in this case, he will align your iframe to the center of the page).

Let me know if it worked. :)

Comment: thank you so much, just watched a video about flexbox containers and this is going to be super helpful, thanks for telling me about it !

Answer (score 0):

This actually should be a comment, but I want to demonstrate what I write by using code, so here it is:

What do you mean when you write "whenever I change the left or right properties it doesn't actually move"?

I changed the `left`  setting of your code in the the snippet below to `200px`(it's the only change I made), and the position of the iFrame *is* different than in you original snippet! (it's 200px left of the parent's left border, opposed to 500px in your snippet).

*???*

```css
.things1 {
  position: relative;
}

.afx-vid {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="things1">
  <iframe class="afx-vid" width="300" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rndV_5q8Tkc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem if I understand you correctly. I had an iFrame and I gave it a style by giving it the class-attribute and in the CSS for that class I tried to give it:

```
    position: absolute; 
    left    : 200px;
    right   : 0px; 
    top     : 0px;
    bottom  : 0px;
```

But the left and right positions had no effect. The IFrame did not "move" to where I wanted it.

For every other type of element using CSS this way seems to work but there is something about iFrame that makes it different.

Then I finally discovered a somewhat round-about way to make it position like I wanted by doing the following:

1. In the HTML for the IFrame-element give it:

   width="100%"
   height="100%"

Note above is HTML, not CSS

2. In the HTML wrap the IFrame element inside a  DIV  and give that div a style-class named for example 'iFrameWrapper'.  Give that wrapper-class  the attributes like these:

**.iFrameWrapper
{
position  : absolute;
left      : 210px;
right     : 0px ;
top       : 0px;
bottom    : 0px;
}**

Now the iFrameWrapper -DIV AND the IFrame -element inside inside it  position correctly.

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="iFrameWrapper">
  <iFrame width  = 100%;
          height = 100%;
          src    = "..."
  ></iframe>
</div>
```

SUMMARY:
Make the iFrame element have HTML attribute-values height="100%" width="100%" and wrap it inside an absolutely positioned DIV. Then position that wrapper-div with CSS anyway you want.